# Реализация сигналов и слотов в своём классе

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Начал изучать Qt по книге М.Шлее и дошёл до сигналов и слотов, сам механизм понятен. Попробовал написать простой класс реализующий этот механизм, но Qt Creator выводит похожие ошибки

> .../Error in " Util.asciify("build-...-Debug")":-1: error: TypeError:
>   Property 'asciify' of object
>   Core::Internal::UtilsJsExtension(0x155bb00) is not a
>   function/.../tests.cpp:19: undefined reference to
>   `SS_Primer::introduce_yourself()'

Класс компилируется

```
class SS_primer : public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        void send_signal() { emit introduce_yourself(); }
    public slots:
        void show_name() { std::cout << "I'm a slot" << std::endl; }
    signals:
        void introduce_yourself();
};
```

А этот код не хочет(

```
bool Test::SignalSlot() {
    SS_primer primer;
    QObject::connect( &primer, SIGNAL(introduce_yourself()), &primer, SLOT(show_name()) );
    primer.send_signal();
    return true;
}
```

Пробовал создавать объект класса через new, делал send_signal() static функцией принимающей указатель.

Comment: в интернетах пишут, что надо убрать галку с Теневой сборки

Comment: я плохо знаком с QI: но, думаю, сначала нужно послать сигнал  primer.send_signal(); а потом уж связать со слотом. И еще нужно написать определение  introduce_yourself()

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, нет, сначала соединить со слотом, а потом отправлять сигналы. Иначе сигнал не дойдет до получателя, так как получателя нет. Определение сигнала добавлять не нужно, оно автоматически создаётся метаобъектным компилятором (moc).

Comment: @Nenez: попробуйте принудительно вызвать qmake (правой кнопкой на проект - запустить qmake). Потом пересоберите проект.

Comment: @maestro,  логично,  спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вангую: Вы сделали все это дело в одном файле, не так ли? Вам следовало повнимательнее почитать Шлее, иначе бы Вы были бы вкурсе, что такое и, главное, как работает метакомпилятор. Короче разнести объявление и реализацию как положено и все заработает.

PS Эти ошибки выводит не мифический Qt, а линкер - он вам прямо говорит, что не может найти ваш сигнал. Его действительно нет - можете даже создать динамическую библиотеку и проверить `nm`-ом. Это из-за того, что `moc` не отработал.

PSS используйте новый синтаксис сигналов-слотов - он гораздо удобнее (за исключением перегруженный слотов) и при ошибках, связанных с неправильным подключением, вы получите больше корректной информации.

Comment: `за исключением перегруженный слотов` - начиная с 5.8 появилась возможность использовать макрос `qOverload` для работы с перегруженными сигналами и слотами. Это удобно.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. МОС и линкер рассматриваются у Шлее в следующей главе.